# Disable default namespace or disconnect all sockets connection to default namespace in socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a socket.io server running on node in which I am allowing different third party applications to connect to different namespaces.

I do not want anyone connecting to default namespace `/` there by intend to disable default namespace permanently or disconnect all sockets  on `connection` to the default namespace

Below is section of my code:

Server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var nsp={};
var namespaces = ["/news","/world","/chat"];
for(var i=0;i < namespaces.length;i++){
    namesp = namespaces[i];
    nsp[namesp] = io.of(namesp);
    nsp[namesp].on('connection', function(socket){

    // some code here

    });
}
```

If I try connecting to default namespace with the above code it still accepts the connection.

Added the below code in server:

```
io.of("/").on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.disconnect("unauthorized");
});
```

Turns out all the connections goes to above code if defined. So couldn't close sockets separately for default namespace connected ones.

I also tried removing the default namespace using

```
delete io.nsps['/'];
```

doesn't seem to work.

I am new to socket.io. Any solution to solve it?

Comment: Have you found out how to close/unauthorize the default namespace?

Comment: Not yet. Initially I was trying to handle the default namespace connect also in server to make the connect close on connect but when i define it in server it started to close all connections including the ones that should connect other namespaces too. So it remove it and left it as it is.

Comment: Is there a way on client side to detect the namespace does not exist?

Comment: I have seen namespace of a socket after connection within the socket variable when i tried printing it in console of the browser. You can try that but its been long not sure it is the same on latest versions of socket.io